# A Diamond issue with Multiple Inheritance: Error in Gcc / Clang but no error in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, multiple-inheritance

I have the following multiple inheritance structure with an empty base and two empty derived classes (both representing different functionality, but that's all left out here). I have another class that needs both these functionalities and as such inherits from both interfaces. The set-up below compiles fine using visual studio 2015, but not with gcc 6 or clang3.8. gcc complains about Base is an ambiguous base class of DerivedC

gcc error:

```
error: ‘Base’ is an ambiguous base of ‘DerivedC’
std::cout << "derivedC.typeId()" << dc.typeId() << std::endl;
```

Clang error:

```
ambiguous conversion from derived class 'DerivedC' to base class    'const Base':
class DerivedC -> class DerivedA -> class Base
class DerivedC -> class DerivedB -> class Base
    std::cout << "derivedC.typeId()" << dc.typeId() << std::endl;
```

In usage of these classes I need to cast a (pointer to) Base model to a (pointer to) DerivedC model. If I would make the multiple inheritance virtual, I need to do a dynamic_cast which I want to avoid. Is there any way I can make gcc and clang understand which direction of the diamond I want to take? It seems to me that the "using DerivedA::typeId" handles this (as it does in VS(it does complain if the using is missing)). Interestingly, VS does "indicate a ambiguous base error" problem when you hover over the code. However, it does compile it and returns the desired values.

Any help much appreciated.
Mike

code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:

int typeId() const {
    return doTypeId();
}
private:
virtual int doTypeId() const = 0;
};

class DerivedA : public Base
{
public:

private:
virtual int doTypeId() const override { return 1; }
};

class DerivedB : public Base
{
public:

private:
virtual int doTypeId() const override { return 2; }
};

class DerivedC : public DerivedA, public DerivedB
{
public:
using DerivedA::typeId;
private:
virtual int doTypeId() const override { return 3; }
};

int main(void) {
  auto da = DerivedA();
  std::cout << "DerivedA.typeId() = " << da.typeId() << std::endl;
  auto db = DerivedB();
  std::cout << "DerivedB.typeId() = " << db.typeId() << std::endl;
  auto dc =  DerivedC();
  std::cout << "derivedC.typeId() = " << dc.typeId() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Read about virtual inheritance.   Do you one one instance of Base, or do you one one instance in DerivedA and another different one in DerivedB?

Comment: I know about virtual inheritance, but as I point out this leads to needing a dynamic_cast elsewhere which I want to avoid. My question is: is Visual Studio correct in letting this through or are Clang / gcc correct. If so, is there a way to make it work without using virtual inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have not used virtual inheritance, you do not have a diamond.  You have two instances of Base

```
         --------         --------
         | Base |         | Base |
         |  #1  |         |  #2  |
         --------         --------
            V                V
         ------------    ------------
         | DerivedA |    | DerivedB |
         ------------    ------------
                 V         V 
                ------------ 
                | DerivedC | 
                ------------
```

That means the v-table for DerivedC has two slots for the virtual method doTypeId().  Which one does the definition of doTypeId() in Derived C override?
[That's not the actual problem here, but it is one you will have to cope with if you solve this problem]

The 'using' statement doesn't solve the problem.  It hoists the declaration of the method out of the DerivedA class into the context where the `using` appears.  If the signature of the method in DerivedB was different, it would be hidden by the `using`, but since it is the same, it is still available.

The name is not declared in DerivedC, but the compiler does not keep track of where the name came from.  Hence the call is still ambiguous.  In order to call a member declared in `Base` it has to know what to pass as the `this` pointer and it can't tell.

Bottom Line: Use virtual inheritance.

Comment: "Which one does the definition of doTypeId() in Derived C override?" Both. This is not a problem at all. The compiler complains about the call to (non-virtual) `typeId`, not `doTypeId`.

Comment: OK, I'll edit my answer accordingly, but the problem is still caused by having two instance of Base in each DerivedC, and the answer is still virtual inheritance.

Comment: Ok, it was not entirely an answer to my question, but it seems fair to accept it. I would conclude: 1) No, you cannot work around using virtual inheritance. 2) Visual Studio has a bug that it still compiles the code.

Comment: @Mike VC++ clearly has a bug, the standard discusses a very similar example and says the using-declaration cannot be used to disambiguate.

Comment: @Mike you can get away without v.i. if you define a separate `typeId` in `DerivedC`. But it is not recommended for a number of reasons.

Comment: @DaleWilson This isn't ever a problem to cope with. A declaration of a member function overrides all virtual member functions with the same signature from all base classes. It doesn't matter whether the member function ultimately comes from the same ancestor or from different ancestors. You can do `struct A{virtual int x();}; struct B{virtual int x();}; struct C:A,B{int x();};` and there's no question of what happens here. In terms of vtables, **there's only one slot for x() in C.vtable**.